# CP1251 → CP866 для Memo1.Text

Tags: delphi, кодировка

Доброго времени суток. Вопрос прост. Читаю txt файл в `Memo`, всё грузится, но там неизвестный науке язык. С помощью декодера Лебедева я понял, что кодировка эта `CP866` и начал сооружать установку по перекодированию, но столкнулся с проблемой типов данных. Кодировать пытался `OemToAnsi` и наоборот тоже, при этом вылазит ошибка что `Memo1.Text` имеет тип `PWideChar` что в принципе и понятно. Привожу фрагмент когда который в настоящее время является проблемным:

```
Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile('###.txt');
WinToDos(Memo1.Lines.GetText);
n:= Memo1.Lines.GetText;
CharToOem(n,n);
Memo1.Lines.Text := StrPas(n);
```

Прошу указать на возможный обход проблемы или предложить иное, возможно более короткое решение данной проблемы. Заранее Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась следующим образом:

```
SetCodePage(ss, CP_ACP, False);
```

где:

`ss: RawByteString`;

`CP_ACP` - кодировка, вариантов кстати масса, а чтобы узнать к какой кодировке принадлежат ваши крокозябры, можно использовать онлайн сервис http://foxtools.ru/Text ;

`False` - я так и не понял что это за штука, но если поставить в этом положении, то произойдёт перекодировка.

Answer (score 0):

Было бы неплохо сделать так:

```
ss: String;
SetCodePage(RawByteString(ss), CP_ACP, False);
```

То есть сначала загнать весь текст в переменную типа "String", потом её перекодировать, использовав "RawByteString", а потом уже её записывать в Memo. А то пришлось на англоязычный сайт лезть, чтоб разобраться, как этим пользоваться. Но всё равно спасибо за наводку!